# close bootstrap collapse menu when clicking on navbar-brand

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get the collapsed `navbar` - when open - to close when the `navbar-brand` title is clicked. At the moment if the bootstrap collapsed navbar is open and the navbar-brand (which in this case says 'fried onions') is clicked, the navbar does not close. It closes in all other instances.

I think I just need to add `a` to `'.navbar-collapse.in'` so it's really just a syntax issue. I tried `'.navbar-collapse.in' && 'a'` and also `'.navbar-collapse.in || a'` neither worked.

[Here's a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0qhrTjCAmpk1HwddMkJC?p=preview)

And here's the relevant JS.

```
   $(document).on('click','.navbar-collapse.in',function(e) {
    if( $(e.target).is('a') && $(e.target).attr('class') != 'dropdown-toggle' ) {
        $(this).collapse('hide');
    }
});


  $(document).ready(function () {

    $(function () {
     /*   $('li a').click(function (e) { */
        $('a').click(function (e) {
            $('a').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Bootstrap** actually opens and closes the navbar using the HTML5 `data-*` attributes `data-toggle` and `data-target`. These are generally added to the "close" button of the navbar like `data-toggle="collapse"` and `data-target="#navbar"`. But you can add them anywhere and they'll work.

I have tried this and it seems to work:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" ui-sref="home">Fried <span class="navbar-brand-bold">Onions</span></a>
```

It's just adding the `data-toggle="collapse"` and `data-target="#navbar"` to the `.navbar-brand` ("Fried Onions").

### Edit:

If the above solution doesn't work, then remove the `data-toggle` and `data-target` from `.navbar-brand` and add some **jQuery** instead:

```
$(function(){
  $(".navbar-brand").click(function(){
    if ($(".collapse.in")) {
      $(".collapse.in").animate({height: '1px'}, 500, function(){
        $(".collapse.in").removeClass("in");
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: @AgentZebra `data-toggle` and `data-target` are `data-*` attributes. They are generally the same as any ordinary HTML attribute, but Bootstrap uses them to recognize and run many of it's JS components. So by adding `data-toggle="collapse"` to any HTML element tells Bootstrap to bind it's `collapse` feature to that element. Similarly, the `data-target="#navbar"` tells Bootstrap which element to show/hide (open/collapse).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This almost fixes it. However now when the collapsed nav is not open, and I click on the navbar-brand / fried onions, it actually opens the collapsed nav and leaves it open.

Comment: @AgentZebra No problem. Happy coding!